# Checking if a variable contains a floating-point value

Tags: r, floating-point, integer, number-formatting

In the R language, is there any reliable method of checking if a variable is floating-point or integer-valued?

I have looked at several proposed solutions. The R helpfile for `is.integer(x)` suggests using the `round(x)` function, as such:

```
is.wholenumber <- function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)  abs(x - round(x)) < tol
```

However, this is checking for *whole number*, not a number *with a floating point*. This function would return `TRUE` for the cases of `1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ...` where there is no fractional part of the value, but still a floating-point in its notation.

It boggles me that I haven't found a simple solution for checking this in R as it is designed to deal with manipulating large tables of (often heterogeneous) data. I need this particular solution as I am applying manipulations to data that are conditional on their type due to the potential data ranges across the whole dataset. So, if my algorithm comes across a value of the nature `1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ...`, it should know that a particular manipulation is applicable.

I have tried converting the value to a string using `sprintf()` and then checking if the string contains a period. This has the obvious issue of formatting the number based on the specifier, hence:

```
x = 5.0
y = 5
sprintf("%f", x) # "5.000000"
sprintf("%f", y) # "5.000000"
sprintf("%d", x) # "5"
sprintf("%d", y) # "5"
```

As shown, there is no way to differentiate them.

EDIT: For more detail on my application and why this solution is needed.

I am working with large tables of data and therefore I am not defining the data myself. Part of my algorithm involves taking a row of data, incremementing/decrementing its values and passing it through a classifier to look for changes in the  outcome. For simplicity, I am only considering numeric values. In terms of how the data is formatted, different numerical types can undergo different manipulations. A real-valued feature can be incrememented/decremented in fractional steps, e.g. `5.0, 4.8, 4.6, 4.4, ...` whereas an integer-valued feature must be manipulated in whole steps, e.g. `5, 4, 3, 2, ...`

I want to calculate the increment when I identify the data type of the feature. Thus, if the feature value is `32`, the algorithm will increment/decrement in *whole* steps. If the feature value is `5.9`, the algorithm will increment/decrement in *fractional* steps.

The problem is when the algorithm encounters a floating-point value of `5.0`. This signifies that it is in the real-valued domain, but it is judged as a whole number according to R's functionality.

If I cannot find a solution for this, I will have to predefine the data type of each column in each table.

Some sample data from the *diabetes* dataset: https://pastebin.com/5FTsaC0g

Comment: In languages like Python or Rust, if you define `x = 5.0` and `y = 5`, `x` is a float and `y` is an integer. But in R they're both numeric with the exact same byte representation (try `serialize(x,connection = NULL, ascii = TRUE) == serialize(y,connection = NULL, ascii = TRUE)` ). You would need to do `y = 5L` to store an integer. So there is no way to differentiate your `x` and `y` values as they stand as they're not different. However, `is.integer()` will return different values for `5` and `5L`. This is probably what you want but if not can you provide more detail?

Comment: Note that `5.0 == 5`, so this doesn't make sense to me. You might want to `dput` example data or provide  a specific use-case to clarify what you're after.

Comment: I have provided an edit that goes into more detail about the use case. Thank you.

Comment: @GabrielSaul can you post some sample data e.g. `dput(head(df))`. It sounds like what you're saying is that there are certain columns which contain values that must be considered as integers because of their nature (e.g. counts). That's quite a different proposition to judging an individual number - why not just use the `is.wholenumber()` function? If your data is more than a handful or rows and it's `TRUE` for an entire column then you can fairly confidently assume you're dealing a column of integers.

Comment: @SamR That is a good idea. I did consider that, and it's not a fool-proof solution, but I can rewrite it such that the worst-case scenario would be that a real-valued feature may occasionally undergo whole-step mutations. This is vastly better than the inverse. I will implement this for now, but I will keep the question open as I believe a general solution should be available for this. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to say is that in R, there is no difference between `5` and `5.0`. As the [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Constants) sets out:

> Perhaps unexpectedly, the number returned from the expression `1` is a numeric... We can use the `"L"` suffix to qualify any number with the intent of making it an explicit integer.

```r
class(5) # numeric
class(5.0) # numeric
class(5L) # integer
```

However, it sounds like this a case where you have a large-ish dataset that you have not defined, and you need to establish which columns are discrete and which are continuous.

We can use `mtcars` as an example as all values stored as floats but some are actually discrete (e.g. number of gears, horsepower). Let's convert to a `tibble` so it prints column types nicely:

```r
dat <- dplyr::as_tibble(mtcars)
head(dat, n = 2)
# # A tibble: 6 × 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
# 2  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
```

You can use the base R [`type.convert()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/type.convert.html) to infer the column types for you:

```r
head(type.convert(dat, as.is = TRUE), n = 2)
# # A tibble: 2 × 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
# 2    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
```

Or if you just want the column types:

```r
sapply(type.convert(dat, as.is = TRUE), class)
#       mpg       cyl      disp        hp      drat        wt      qsec        vs        am      gear      carb 
# "numeric" "integer" "numeric" "integer" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer"
```

Obviously there is technically a non-zero chance that you could have a continuous variable where all the values happen to be exactly an integer, but I wouldn't worry about this unless you have a tiny number of rows or *extremely* imprecise measurements.

Comment: This works great for my use case. Thank you for this. I'm opting for the data frame of class types underneath the column names to use as a reference such that I don't alter the table in case it causes issues with the classifier. However, I'm assuming this only works with tables of data. Due to R's language definition, is there really no solution for identifying floating-point notation in a single variable? In other words, `5.0 == 5` and that's final!

Comment: @GabrielSaul yes `c(5)` and `c(5.0)` are identical `numeric` vectors of length one in R.

Comment: @GabrielSaul Note that `identical(5, 5L) == FALSE`.

Comment: @SamR Thank you again for this solution. As it works for my use case, I will select it as a top answer. I suppose this really is mostly necessary when working with data frames, but a general use case for individual values would be a useful addition to R.